# Using new Groovy Grape capability results in "unable to resolve class" error

Tags: grails, groovy, groovy-grape

I've tried to use the new [Groovy Grape](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape) capability in Groovy 1.6-beta-2 but I get an error message;

```
unable to resolve class com.jidesoft.swing.JideSplitButton
```

from the Groovy Console (/opt/groovy/groovy-1.6-beta-2/bin/groovyConsole) when running the stock example;

```
import com.jidesoft.swing.JideSplitButton
@Grab(group='com.jidesoft', module='jide-oss', version='[2.2.1,)')
public class TestClassAnnotation {
    public static String testMethod () {
        return JideSplitButton.class.name
    }
}
```

I even tried running the grape command line tool to ensure the library is imported.  Like this;

```
 $ /opt/groovy/groovy-1.6-beta-2/bin/grape install com.jidesoft jide-oss
```

which does install the library just fine.  How do I get the code to run/compile correctly from the groovyConsole?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is still some kinks in working out the startup/kill switch routine.  For Beta-2 do this in it's own script first:

```
groovy.grape.Grape.initGrape()
```

Another issue you will run into deals with the joys of using an unbounded upper range.  Jide-oss from 2.3.0 onward has been compiling their code to Java 6 bytecodes, so you will need to either run the console in Java 6 (which is what you would want to do for Swing anyway) or set an upper limit on the ranges, like so

```
import com.jidesoft.swing.JideSplitButton

@Grab(group='com.jidesoft', module='jide-oss', version='[2.2.1,2.3.0)')
public class TestClassAnnotation {
    public static String testMethod () {
        return JideSplitButton.class.name
    }
}

new TestClassAnnotation().testMethod()
```

Answer (score 5):

I finally got it working for Groovy Shell (1.6.5, JVM: 1.6.0_13). This should be documented better.

First at the command line...

> grape install org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder http-builder 0.5.0-RC2

Then in groovysh...

```
groovy:000> import groovy.grape.Grape
groovy:000> Grape.grab(group:'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module:'http-builder', version:'0.5.0-RC2')
groovy:000> def http= new groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder('http://rovio')
===> groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder@91520
```

The @grab is better used in a file than the shell.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Seems like this a short working demo (running from the groovyConsole)

```
groovy.grape.Grape.initGrape()
@Grab(group='com.jidesoft', module='jide-oss', version='[2.2.1,2.3.0)')
public class UsedToExposeAnnotationToComplier {}
com.jidesoft.swing.JideSplitButton.class.name
```

When run it produces

Result: "com.jidesoft.swing.JideSplitButton"

Very cool!!

Comment: This worked great for me. The empty class is key. Couple of points... 1/ I didn't need the initGrape() line (using groovy 1.7x or 1.8x).. 2/ If you are behind a proxy make sure to add your proxy settings -Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxyhost> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxyPort>... I add them to my startGroovy.sh|bat

Answer (score 0):

The import statement must appear **after** the grabs.

Ps. At least **one import** statement must exists after the grabs

```java
@Grab(group='com.jidesoft', module='jide-oss', version='[2.2.1,)')
import com.jidesoft.swing.JideSplitButton
public class TestClassAnnotation {
    public static String testMethod () {
        return JideSplitButton.class.name
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Different example using latest RC-2 (note: Grab annotates createEmptyInts):

```
// create and use a primitive array
import org.apache.commons.collections.primitives.ArrayIntList

@Grab(group='commons-primitives', module='commons-primitives', version='1.0')
def createEmptyInts() { new ArrayIntList() }

def ints = createEmptyInts()
ints.add(0, 42)
assert ints.size() == 1
assert ints.get(0) == 42
```

Comment: Examples stolen from http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape. (copied exactly)

Also, it does not answer the question.

Comment: I agree. Please refer people to correct answers if you find them elsewhere on the web. Provide a link. Please don't take credit for other people's work without attribution.

Answer (score -1):

Another example (note: Grab annotates getHtml):

```
// find the PDF links in the Java 1.5.0 documentation
@Grab(group='org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup', module='tagsoup', version='0.9.7')
def getHtml() {
    def parser = new XmlParser(new org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser())
    parser.parse("http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/download-pdf.html")
}
html.body.'**'.a.@href.grep(~/.*\.pdf/).each{ println it }
```

Comment: Examples stolen from http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape. (copied exactly)

Also, it does not answer the question.

Answer (score -3):

Another example (note: `Grab` annotates `getFruit`):

```
// Google Collections example
import com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap
@Grab(group='com.google.code.google-collections', module='google-collect', version='snapshot-20080530')
def getFruit() { [grape:'purple', lemon:'yellow', orange:'orange'] as HashBiMap }
assert fruit.inverse().yellow == 'lemon'
```

Comment: Examples stolen from http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape. (copied exactly)

Also, it does not answer the question.